# How to specify not null constraint for object in list in bean validation

Tags: java, validation, annotations, javabeans

```
class Person{

    //insert some validation annotation here to make sure that list CANNOT contain null entry
    private List<String> addressList;

   //rest of the code
}
```

I need to validate to  make sure that addressList cannot contain any null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javax.validation.constraints.NotNull annotation for addressList to put a restriction this should not be null.
Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html

Comment: If i give @notNull  for addressList , then doesnt it validate to check if the addresslist is notnull nor not.. i want to make sure that the object inside that list cannot be null... i dint understand groups concept in that link u gave, if u r saying we need to use that concept to solve this problem, in that case please explain with an actual example.

Comment: @stallion : NotNull will only put validation on addressList that addressList should not be null. It will not check the each content of the addressList and validate the same. Why we can't add the restriction at first place where we are adding data into `addressList`?